# Material UI Box Border for float-right bootstrap element

Tags: bootstrap-4, material-ui

Using a Material UI Box to show border which consist of a bootstrap element

```
  <input
      type="submit"
      className="btn btn-primary float-right"
      value="Send"
  />
```

Here is the code sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-forest-81kn0?file=/src/App.js:490-501

The Send Button appears outside the Box when *float-right* is used. Send Button appears inside the Box when *float-right* is removed.

How to make it float to right while also making it within the Material UI Box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you could use style to make this. In your input define a style like:

```
<input
   style={styles.input}
   type="submit"
   className="btn btn-primary"
   value="Send"
/>
```

Then in style set `display: "flex"` and `marginLeft: "auto"` in this way:

```
const styles = {
  input: {
    display: "flex",
    marginLeft: "auto"
  }
};
```

and button will appears in form, floated on right.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-lumiere-no0hs?file=/src/App.js) your codesandbox modified.